# Breaking out of loop causes different results

Tags: regex, perl

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $judge_exes = {
    "^A" => "foo",
    "^B" => "bar",
    "^C" => "baz",
};

sub get_judge {
    my ($test_id) = @_;
    my $exe = undef;
    while (my ($regex, $judge) = each %$judge_exes) {
        if ($test_id =~ /$regex/) {
            $exe = $judge;
            last;
        }
    }

    if ($exe) {
        return $exe;
    } else {
        return "Undefined!";
    }
}

print get_judge("A1");
print get_judge("B2");
print get_judge("C3");
```

(ideone: http://ideone.com/slxebG)

I expect to get the output `foobarbaz`, but I end up getting `fooUndefined!baz`. However, when I comment out the `last` statement, I get the correct behavior:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $judge_exes = {
    "^A" => "foo",
    "^B" => "bar",
    "^C" => "baz",
};

sub get_judge {
    my ($test_id) = @_;
    my $exe = undef;
    while (my ($regex, $judge) = each %$judge_exes) {
        if ($test_id =~ /$regex/) {
            $exe = $judge;
            # last;
        }
    }

    if ($exe) {
        return $exe;
    } else {
        return "Undefined!";
    }
}

print get_judge("A1");
print get_judge("B2");
print get_judge("C3");
```

(ideone: http://ideone.com/QJpxbK)

Why is this happening? (I'm on Perl 5.16.2, but the issue is also present on 5.10.1 and whatever ideone is using.)

- As far as I understand, `last` just breaks out of the `while` loop, which is what I want.
- `$exe` doesn't seem to be an alternative falsey value causing me to hit the wrong if-branch. (I could return early, which would be better, but I still wouldn't understand the cause of this.)
- I think I'm dereferencing the hash reference correctly.
- I didn't think that regex matching would have any side effects relating to loop termination.
- The regexes seem to be matching correctly, since I can actually get them to match appropriately under some circumstances, so I don't think it's an interpolation issue.
- I'm not modifying the container that I'm iterating over.

Am I just making some silly non-Perl related mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You have become confused. I am not sure where the confusion lies, but you must be aware that the `each` operator maintains its state between calls. That means your `last` inside the `while` loop won't terminate the iteration. Instead it will continue where it last left off when it is next encountered.

You should also be sparing with double-quotes, as they interpolate any scalar or array variables, or backslashed control characters.

Here is how I suggest that you write your algorithm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $judge_exes = {
    '^A' => 'foo',
    '^B' => 'bar',
    '^C' => 'baz',
};

say get_judge('A1', $judge_exes);
say get_judge('B2', $judge_exes);
say get_judge('C3', $judge_exes);
say get_judge('D4', $judge_exes);
say get_judge('E5', $judge_exes);

sub get_judge {
    my ($test_id, $judges) = @_;

    for my $re ( keys %$judges ) {
        return 1 if $test_id =~ /$re/;
    }

    'Undefined!';
}
```

**output**

```
1
1
1
Undefined!
Undefined!
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it looks like the behavior is [explained here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=How%20do%20I%20reset%20an%20each()%20operation%20part-way%20through%3F):

> Using `keys %hash` in scalar context returns the number of keys in the hash and resets the iterator associated with the hash. You may need to do this if you use `last` to exit a loop early so that when you re-enter it, the hash iterator has been reset.

Wasn't expecting that — I had assumed that `each` would reset the iterator.

Comment: Also explained in [`perldoc -f each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html)

Comment: That certainly looks to be the problem.  When I added diagnostic printing, it seemed that the `each` was not being reset on subsequent entries to the loop (testing with Perl 5.20.0).  I'd got as far as "'each` is not resetting"; I'd not got as far as the documentation for it.  Thoroughly counter-intuitive!

Comment: The OP's code doesn't use `keys`, and that is the problem, It's an odd citation to illustrate the principle. `keys %hash` generates a list that you can iterate using `for` independently of any changes to the hash. But `each %hash` returns a new key/value pair every time it is called, regardless of context and as any good iterator should

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The confusion arises because Perl has no in-built *iterator* objects, and tries to do it anonymously. Perl's `keys` and `values` generate static lists, while `each` creates an anonymous iterator object that is tied to the hash, and will not change state until the next time `each` on the same hash is called. Python and Lua do the same thing, and anything beginning with `C` doesn't get a chance to

Comment: @Borodin: It mostly makes sense; I simply hadn't run into it before, either because I let the iterators complete or because I'm working with non-global hashes so that each time the function is called, it is working on a different hash and hence the `each` starts anew.  Or pure bad luck...I wasn't paying attention, or happened never to have hit the problem.  It is somewhat counter-intuitive when first encountered, but makes enough sense once you know what's going on.  It's one of the nice things about SO; you can learn from it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `keys` and `values` use the same intrinsic iterator as `while`, but always exhaust all of the rest of the hash. So if you're worried about exiting a `while ( my ($k, $v) = each %hash ) { ... }` loop leaving the iterator incomplete then you can reset the iterator using `keys` in a void context, like `if ( $terminating_condition ) { keys %hash; last; }`